# installing microsoft server 2008 on RAID drive

Tags: windows-server-2008, hardware-raid, drivers

Using RAID 1 on a HP G165 G5 server and trying to install windows server 2008, however right at the install screen the windows installation wont find any hard drives.

Ive tried installing [HP 4/8 Internal Port SAS HBA with RAID and SCxxGe series HBA Driver for Windows Server 2008 x64 Editions](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/SoftwareDescription.jsp?lang=en&cc=us&prodTypeId=15351&prodSeriesId=3580133&prodNameId=3580176&swEnvOID=4024&swLang=8&mode=2&taskId=135&swItem=MTX-8ba525521efb4211b04ab9899d) driver, but windows installer wont take it since its unsigned.

Any suggestions on how to accomplish this?

Comment: What disks have you got in there and can you confirm you've installed the SC40Ge controller?

Comment: There's also a note in the quickspecs that says "NOTE: A diskette drive is needed to install storage controller drivers during a Windows operating system installation from CD." - have you done this? also what EXACT operating system are you installing, as in very specific version please.

Comment: Just so you understand these things, Windows neither knows nor cares that you are using RAID. What it DOES care about is that you supply the correct drivers. If in doubt, read the documentation.

Comment: I believe the quickspecs note only applies to Windows Server 2003 installations. Server 2008 installer is capable of reading drivers off a USB stick.

Answer (score 0):

is that a software RAID? if so, then most likely you need to install the drivers first. I remember I had the same issue with a software RAID server setup too, and I had to install the drivers for the RAID at the beginning of the setup, otherwise windows wouldn't find the disk drives.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you've got the right driver? Did you try the [SATA controller driver](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/SoftwareDescription.jsp?lang=en&cc=us&prodTypeId=15351&prodSeriesId=3580133&prodNameId=3580176&swEnvOID=4024&swLang=8&mode=2&taskId=135&swItem=MTX-781519775fa045178c70d03da5) as well?